# Scrolling the scrollbar of a ConsoleApplication hangs the thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application

I've got some server apps that I've been trying to get some metrics from so I can debug them. I found that when scrolling back up the window I'd suddenly get timeouts from the clients. Sure enough, moving the scrollbar stopped the application.

I'm probably missing something fundemental here, but I can't work out why moving the scrollbar on a Console window would block the thread.

It's very simple to reproduce:

```
Sub Main()
    Do
        Console.WriteLine(Now.ToString("O"))
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Run that up, and any interaction with the window blocks the thread. In the example below, I just moved the scrollbar a bit and held it in position for a few seconds before releasing

[image]
http://www.briandrought.com/miscpics/scrollbar.png

I've tried it with a Timer type loop rather than a Thread.Sleep but the same issue appears. What am I doing wrong (other than not using a service instead!)?

Kind Regards,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong. That's just how windows console apps behave. In normal operation your server apps would surely run as headless services so there should be no issue in production.