# Why is the Console pausing my code when I click on the scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net

Run this code in a C# Console Application:

```
long last = 0;
long curr = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

while (true)
{
    last = curr;
    curr = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
    var delta = ((curr - last) / (float)Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000;
    Console.WriteLine(delta);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
 }
```

This source should print out some steady numbers like

- ...
- 62.234235
- 62.123134
- 62.589342
- 62.423423
- ...

And while this is running hold the scroll button for some seconds. While you are holding the button the outputs should stop cause the Thread is sleeping....

The next output when u release is smt. like this:

- ...
- 62.234235
- 62.123134   <--- Holding the Scroll button
- 2540.342112 <--- Release
- 62.589342
- 62.423423
- ...

Now my question:
Is there a way to stop the Console from telling my Thread a goodnight story when I am scrolling?

Comment: So is your question "Why does holding down the scroll wheel appear to pause the thread?"

Comment: Arqade may [have the meme](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2196/3638) of having funny titles but Stack overflow does not.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143628/scrolling-the-scrollbar-of-a-consoleapplication-hangs-the-thread (or that older question is a duplicate of this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way.

`Console.WriteLine` is a **blocking operation**. When you scroll, you are preventing this call to complete, but the stopwatch continues to run.

The number you are seeing when you release the scroll is basically 50 + How long you keep holding the scrolling button.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a:

```
ConcurrentQueue<float> deltasQueue;
```

Then, start a second background thread that executes the code as you have it, but instead of doing Console.WriteLine(delta), insert the delta into the deltasQueue.

Your main thread, after starting the background thread, should have a loop that takes items off the deltasQueue as they arrive and do Console.WriteLine(delta) with them.

This way, your code that produces deltas can run without blocking. Only your main thread that displays them will block. When the user stops scrolling, the console will appear to suddenly catch up and print all of the deltas that occurred while they were scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking the UI executing any code when holding the scrollbar down. Therefore your program is pausing.

When you release, the code runs and you get your print out of the timing.